# alternative for alter session set week_start in snowflake

Tags: session, parameters, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I need to set week start from sunday as default in snowflake

i used

```
alter session set WEEK_START = 7;
```

when querying in snowflake worksheet it works fine but when using the same query via api it has no effect.

is there any way to set  WEEK_START from sunday without using alter session.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could submit multipe statements per request:
[Specifying Multiple SQL Statements in the Request](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/guide.html#specifying-multiple-sql-statements-in-the-request) and separate them with semicolon.

```
alter session set WEEK_START = 7; SELECT DAYOFWEEK()
```

---

> is there any way to set WEEK_START from sunday without using alter session.

Setting the parameter on USER level that is used for making the API call.

```
ALTER USER <user_name_here> SET WEEK_START = 7;
```

Related [Parameter Hierarchy and Types](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#parameter-hierarchy-and-types)

Answer (score 0):

Try using EXECUTE AS CALLER in SP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to avoid Alter Session, but it is necessary to use a NEXT_DAY function every time you need to use the next Monday for your datetime.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/next_day

SELECT NEXT_DAY(GETDATE(), 'MON')::TIMESTAMP_NTZ as next_monday;

| NEXT_MONDAY |
| --- |
| 2023-11-20 00:00:00.000 |